# Multiple Boxplot with various size of data set labeling

Tags: matlab, dataset, boxplot

I have read carefully the post [Most efficient way of drawing grouped boxplot matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971478/most-efficient-way-of-drawing-grouped-boxplot-matlab/15974087#15974087). The code give by Oleg :

```
Y     = rand(1000,1);
X     = Y-rand(1000,1);
ACTid = randi(6,1000,1);

xylabel = repmat('xy',1000,1);
boxplot([X; Y], {repmat(ACTid,2,1), xylabel(:)} ,'factorgap',10)
% Retrieve handles to text labels
h = allchild(findall(gca,'type','hggroup'));

% Delete x, y labels
throw = findobj(h,'string','x','-or','string','y');
h     = setdiff(h,throw);
delete(throw);

% Center labels
mylbl  = {'this','is','a','pain','in...','guess!'};
hlbl   = findall(h,'type','text');
pos    = cell2mat(get(hlbl,'pos'));

% New centered position for first intra-group label
newPos = num2cell([mean(reshape(pos(:,1),2,[]))' pos(1:2:end,2:end)],2);
set(hlbl(1:2:end),{'pos'},newPos,{'string'},mylbl')

% delete second intra-group label
delete(hlbl(2:2:end))
```

works pefectly fine. However I have a question on the 'handle' structure. In my case I just have a single data per number {1,2,3,4,5,6}, so I don't need the `xylabel` and I used `boxplot([X; Y], {repmat(ACTid,2,1) repmat('x',1000,1)} ,'factorgap',10)` and it works fine. Why do we need to use the x labeling? If I do not use it, the variable `h` has not the 'data source' type and is referenced as 'line' type so the replacement of the number by strings does not work anymore. Does anyone know why?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're really just asking how to change the `XTickLabel` to some strings. If so, this should do the trick:

```
Y     = rand(1000,1);
X     = Y-rand(1000,1);
ACTid = randi(6,1000,1);

boxplot([X; Y],repmat(ACTid,2,1),'factorgap',10);
mylbl  = {'this','is','a','pain','in...','guess!'};
set(gca,'xticklabel',mylbl)
```

**More details:**

The second input to the `boxplot` function is the grouping variable(s). When only one grouping variable is used, `boxplot` just changes `XTickLabel` itself to match the grouping. You can see this by entering `get(gca,'xticklabel')` right after the `boxplot` command:

```
boxplot([X; Y],repmat(ACTid,2,1),'factorgap',10)
get(gca,'xticklabel')
ans = 
    '1'
    '2'
    '3'
    '4'
    '5'
    '6'
```

If more than one grouping variable is used -- e.g. two -- `boxplot` has to be fancy in order to label your boxplots using both groupings (see the picture below), so, it sets `XTickLabel` as empty, then inserts some `text` objects instead. Check out `XTickLabel` after using two grouping variables:

```
boxplot([X; Y], {repmat(ACTid,2,1), xylabel(:)} ,'factorgap',10)
get(gca,'xticklabel')
ans =
     ''
%// It's empty!!!
```

which is why you *do* find `text` objects after using two grouping variables, but *not* when you only use one.

[image: Using two grouping variables]

Comment: Thank you Geoff this is what I wanted to know.