# Sort means for box plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, visualization, matlab-figure, boxplot

I have a dataset in the following structure:

```
Data_1 = [10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
groups_1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5];

Data_2 = [20,12,63,4,5,5,5,2];
groups_2 = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5];

boxplot(Data_1,groups_1);boxplot(Data_2,groups_2);
```

I would like to sort Data_1 according to the mean and group Data_1 and Data_2 next to each other based on the mean of Data_1 into one box plot.
My approach was to use grpstats:

```
Table_1 = array2table([Data_1' groups_1']);
Stats = grpstats(Table_1,'Var2');
sort_Stats = sortrows(Stats,'mean_Var1');
```

Now I am stuck on how to combine the two data sets and the groups based on the grpstats results efficiently.

Update:
I need the following structure as a final goal:

```
Data_Corrected_1 = [3,4,5,6,10,2,7,8,9];
groups_Corrected_1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5];
boxplot(Data_Corrected_1,groups_Corrected_1);
% Now the box plot is arranged based on the mean
```

Comment: Can you add the result you want? Are you saying that for group `1` you want the mean of `[10, 2, 20, 12, 63]` and for `2` the mean of `[3, 4, 63]`? If so then you want to use `accumarray` i.e. `accumarray([groups_1, groups_2].', [Data_1, Data_2].', [], @mean)`

Comment: Thanks! No, I want for group 1 for Data_1 mean for [10,2] and for Data_2 mean for [20,12,63]. Afterwards, I would like to display them next to each other in a box plot group based on the mean. Visualization similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971478/most-efficient-way-of-drawing-grouped-boxplot-matlab

Comment: @C.Colden just use the same code Dan wrote without concatenating groups_1, groups_2 & Data_1,Data_2

Comment: How do I get from the accumarray vector to a box plot sorted according to the means? Would you mind showing an example with data above?

Comment: I just updated the question with a final goal as an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can sort your data based on the means of the groups:

```
Data_1 = [10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
groups_1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5];

[~,ind] = sort(accumarray(groups_1.',Data_1,[],@mean));
ord1 = sortrows([(1:max(groups_1)).' ind],2);
% without repelem:
a = ord1(:,1);
b = histcounts(groups_1);
idx(cumsum([1 b(b>0)])) = 1;
c = a(cumsum(idx(1:find(idx,1,'last')-1)));
Data_Corrected_1 = sortrows([c groups_1.' Data_1.'],1);
% with repelem:
% Data_Corrected_1 = sortrows([repelem(ord1(:,1),histcounts(groups_1))...
%    groups_1.' Data_1.'],1);
boxplot(Data_Corrected_1(:,3),Data_Corrected_1(:,1));
```

[image: sorted_boxplot]

And the same holds for `Data_2`.

Comment: This throughs an error: Undefined function 'repelem' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: @C.Colden What version of Matlab you have?

Comment: I am using 2014b

Comment: @C.Colden [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) was introduced in version 2015a. See my edit for an alternative.